# Cost search operation in a Binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, binary-tree, complexity-theory

How much does it cost the search operation in a Binary tree? Is it O(n)?

Comment: Though given an answer however you could have easily got the answer to your question if you would have typed your question in the search box in either Google or Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do you mean a binary **search** tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        Average     Worst case
Space   O(n)        O(n)
Search  O(log n)    O(n)
Insert  O(log n)    O(n)
Delete  O(log n)    O(n)
```

Comment: @AndreasBrinck, When you have degenerated tree (in other words each node has only 1 child). So, we can consider that tree became linkedlist.

Comment: Yes, I stupidly just read the question as binary search (in an array). Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is O(n), since it is Binary Tree and NOT binary search tree.

Since it is not possible to judge to which way (Left or Right) to branch in a "Binary tree", we have to search the entire tree in the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

Average Case for searching an element: O(log n)

Worst Case: O(n)

You can check out for balanced trees (AVL, Red Black) if you need better (logarithmic) worst case running complexities.

Answer (score 0):

yes It will be O(n) because you have no sorting condintion in this tree like binary search tree, so u have to traverse full tree, just like array

Answer (score 0):

According to the book "An Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms" of Robert Sedgewick, if this binary tree is construct by random permutation of size N, then average successful search is
2H_N − 3 + 2H_N /N = 2ln(N)+O(1), and average of an unsuccessful search is 2H_{N+1} − 2 = 2ln(N)+O(1).